# Should one service take care of both processing Kafka messages and API calls simultaneously?

Tags: rest, apache-kafka, architecture, microservices, publish-subscribe

We want to subscribe to a Kafka topic with a microservice. So that the service does not have to accept API calls from the surrounding systems and Kafka messages at the same time, we would like to interpose an 'importer service'. However, in the end we would have the same problem again because the importer service now has to process both the Kafka messages and the API calls from the aforementioned microservice. As a solution to this problem, we considered giving both services access to the same database. The importer service could then receive the Kafka message, process it and write it to the database. The original microservice would then not go to the importer service, but would get the data directly from the DB. However, the approach seems a bit dirty, since you shouldn't share databases between services. Do you have any ideas how to solve this more elegantly? And if there isn't a better approach, should one service really take care of processing Kafka messages and API calls simultaneously?

Comment: If database separation is your problem, look at CQRS patterns. Also Kafka Connect is commonly used to write to databases, rather than writing your own database client service

Answer (score -1):

One service should not process both kafka and api messages.
You can make a service that wraps the database and both services will communicate with it.

Comment: Sounds like you've not used Kafka Connect, Kafka REST Proxy, KSQL or the Schema Registry, or even Kafka Streams interactive queries. All those are one service with a Kafka client that expose an API.

Comment: All of them are not consuming the same data from kafka.

Comment: Can you please clarify? Kafka Streams consumes and produces data